# Brush algorithm / Color fading pattern - Need suggestions

Tags: c#, algorithm, design-patterns, paint, brush

I'm currently trying to create a simple paint tool but I've come up with a problem, or perhaps need more of a suggestion.

I'm trying to create a Brush, so when I paint a certain pixel "center", it also paints the nearby pixels.

For example:

```
1 pixel (center point)
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][*][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]

2 pixel:
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][*][ ][ ]
[ ][*][*][*][ ]
[ ][ ][*][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]

3 pixels:
[ ][ ][*][ ][ ]
[ ][*][*][*][ ]
[*][*][*][*][*]
[ ][*][*][*][ ]
[ ][ ][*][ ][ ]
```

Also, only the center point should be 100% of the color. How can I later on take the original color and slightly fade it out.

Example:

1 pixels, 100% color

2 pixels, Center point 100% of the color, nearby pixels slightly faded or perhaps (50%)

10 pixels, Center point 100% of the color, the farthest pixel from the center point should be the most faded of the original color.

So an algorithm to calculate the nearby colors and an algorithm to make a brush pattern.

Any suggestions?

Implementation of Color Intensity method (does not work)
Update 1: Changed to Math.Pow(x, y) - slower and doesn't work

```
    public static Color GetColorIntensity(Color c, double r, Point position, Point centerPosition)
    {
        double distance = Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(position.X, 2)) + (Math.Pow(position.Y, 2)));
        double relative_distance = distance / r;
        double alpha = (1.0 - relative_distance);

        return Color.FromArgb((int)alpha, c.R, c.G, c.B);
    }
```

Comment: Sure I could, but I primarly asked for an algorithm to calculate a pattern but I've gotten an algorithm to calculate the color fading instead even though I stated in the comments that I want to be able to solve the algorithm before trying the colors. So how can I accept an answer as "the answer" when Part A of my question needs to be fulfilled before I can try out Solution for B.

Comment: In short: I can't implement it yet because I need a solution to Part A. I don't know if your answer is the right one because I need somewhere to implement it.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you accept an answer on *this* question, but rather on your six other questions.

Comment: As regards your C# solution, in what way does this fail to work? You may want to change `X*2` (X times 2) to `X**2` or `X^2` or possibly `math.pow(X,2)` for "X squared" - however that is said in C#. See [Pythagoras' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem). Also,  the algorithm for calculating the "colour pattern" **is** the algorithm for calculating the colour fading. Are you aware of how [alpha compositing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) works?

Comment: I have given credit to my earlier questions where people pointed in the right direction, but none of the answers I have asked I have fully got "answered" so why say that someone is correct when they left out half the info that I had to figure out myself? I have given +1 to those who have been pointed that way. And some are still unanswered. And, after asking my first question I get 10 answers and then 24 hour later no one answers them anymore. The discussion stops, so why give credit to those who can't participate? Generally; that's the vibe I get from this place.

Comment: About the question here, updated my code and it takes longer to calculate and slows down and doesn't produce the right results. I successfully can draw a Diamond brush right now from the Center point. So, the implementation of your solution isn't working - I know that my Brush implementation is working because it draws a Diamond. Just not that it's faded at the edges. First it rendered a grayish color, then nothing at all, then it slowed down. Single color works fine though.

Comment: Also, since I do not program at all in Python, I might have interpret the implementation wrong.

Comment: Function Arguments: So, if I draw Diamond of Size "3", it's 1 pixel (center) and 2 pixels to the left and 2 pixels to the right. So, Radius should be 5 / 2, and position is the position of the specific pixel, Color c = R G B Alpha (original color), Center Position = X & Y of the center point of the brush.

Comment: Also, if alpha is measured between 0.0f - 1.0f, it should be (255 * Alpha) in C#, but that's neither the problem.

Comment: As I stated earlier, 24 hour per post then if I haven't given credit when there's no answer - I don't get more answers. So, should I just mark an answer as the correct one when people stop participating and have given a half-an-answer? Well... Not me.

Comment: @Deukalion There I gave you a full answer :) 100% complete, I think....

Comment: @Deukalion I am confused, you complain about others not helping you after 24 hours, but here I am.  And 24 hours after I posted my answer you have not even acknowledged me.  And you have been on.  Do you think it's fair to complain about people not reading old posts when you yourself don't even review YOUR old posts.  I even upvoted your question because i thought you did a good job explaining your request.

Comment: @Deukalion Still wondering where you are.  This was a great question, and I would like to know if my answer is what you were looking for?

Answer (score 4):

1. Calculate the distance of each pixel from the centre of the brush.
2. Assign a transparency scaling from `1.0` (centre of brush) to `0.0` (edge of brush.)

If you use the Euclidean distance, `d = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)`, you get a circular brush.

If you use the taxicab distance, `d = abs(x) + abs(y)`, you get a diamond-shaped brush.

Here's Python for a function that calculates the intensity of a pixel with coordinates `x,y` relative to the centre of the brush, with a brush radius of `r`. `a = 1.0` means "full opaque", and `a = 0.0` means "fully transparent".

```
def intensity(x,y,r):
    distance = sqrt( x**2 + y **2 )
    relative_distance = distance / r
    alpha = (1.0 - relative_distance)
    return alpha
```

There's probably an off-by-one error in there (the brush will be one pixel smaller than `r`), but you can fix that yourself.

Comment: Yes, but how do I make the algorithm?

Comment: @Deukalion: See edit. By the way, does your username refer to the book Deukalion?

Comment: Your edit - isn't it only for "color alpha levels?" I'm more interested in getting the "brush" algorithm before I even try changing the colors. If I just use "d = abs(x) + abs(y)" it only gives me one value, which is not what I need. I need to be able to get all pixels from center point to endpoint according to my example in the original post. My name does not refer to the book "Deukalion".

Comment: @Deukalion: You run this function once per `x,y` coordinate within the brush radius. So if your brush has radius `r`, you calculate an alpha value for `(x,y)`, `x in range(-r,r)`, `y in range (-r,r)`.

Comment: I made a C# method that I posted on my post above, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit #2**  Because of my need to solve puzzles, I took the answers others had given, corrected their math mistakes, and came up with what is in my opinion exactly what you are looking for.

try this
I created a new windows form application, I added a numericupdown(size of brush), a trackbar(Fade intensisty) and a button, when you click the button it starts filling in the panels starting from the center and moving outward, the brush number will be solid color, then depending on fade intensity each row outward will be faded more and more.

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Panel[,] pb = new Panel[9, 9];
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //this is just to add the panels to the screen.  
       //We are using panels to simulate zoomed in pixels so we can see what is going on
        for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
            {
                pb[x, y] = new Panel();
                pb[x, y].BackColor = Color.MistyRose;
                pb[x, y].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                pb[x, y].Size = new Size(20, 20);
                pb[x, y].Location = new Point(x * 20, y * 20);
                this.Controls.Add(pb[x,y]);
            }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DrawPixel(new Point(4, 4), (int)numericUpDown1.Value,trackBar1.Value+1);
    }

    public void DrawPixel(Point pixel, int radius,int intensity)
    {
        radius--;
        for (int y = 0; y <= 8; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x <= 8; x++)
            {
                //clears the screen before starting
                pb[x, y].BackColor = Color.White;
                //calculate the distance from the center pixel
                double Distance = Math.Sqrt( ((x-pixel.X)*(x-pixel.X) + (y-pixel.Y) *(y-pixel.Y))-radius*radius );
                //determine color intensity
                int alpha = (int)Distance <= 0 ? 255 : (int)Distance > intensity ? 0 : (int)(intensity - Distance) * 50 > 255 ? 255 : (int)(intensity - Distance) * 50;

                if (alpha>0)
                    pb[x, y].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(alpha, Color.Red);
            }
    }
```

Comment: I just modified my answer I believe it does exactly what you want now, if you need further explanation just ask